# automatic login in android with the session that carries the id of cookis

Tags: java, android, json, authentication, session-cookies

how to make session in android which will bring the session cookies given web service to perform automatic login process. I also asked her how to set expired

Comment: use shared preference to  save a coockis at the time of login  which is provide by your web service and expiration of cookie should be implemented web service side

Comment: whether cookies that are stored on your android device as well or not? if yes, where is the storage?